# Pandas loop over groupby and plot each group

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, group-by

I am trying to loop over a groupby object and plot each group. But I am having some issues. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['item1',2000,1, 2], ['item1',2001,1, 2], ['item1',2002,1, 2], 
              ['item2',2000,1, 2], ['item2',2001,1, 2], ['item2',2002,1, 2]],
              columns=['mykey', 'year','val1','val2'])

grouped = df.groupby('mykey')
for name,group in grouped:
  fig = plt.figure()
  ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
  group.val1.plot.line(ax=ax1, ylim=[5,20], color='red',x=group.year)
  ax1.set_ylabel('val1')
  ax2 = ax1.twinx()
  group.val2.plot.line(ax=ax2, ylim=[5,20], color='blue' ,x=group.year)
  ax2.set_ylabel('val2')
  plt.title(str(name), fontsize=15);
```

It seems I'm close, but just there are some issues some where.

1. First issue is that there are 5 groups in the groupby object. I get the 5 figures as I want, but only first one has the plots(lines) on it. Others figures are blank with the correct title on them,  any idea what is wrong with my code?
2. How can I set a group column / key as the x axis, I have tried this x=group.desiredx but it doesn't do anything.

mykey|  year|   val1|   val2
item1|  2000|   5|  34
item2|  2001|   45| 34
item3|  2002|   34| 34
item1|  2000|   22| 65
item2|  2001|   34| 54
item3|  2002|   12| 54
item1|  2000|   23| 54
item2|  2001|   34| 34
item3|  2002|   21| 21

Comment: Please read and understand [mcve]. The question on [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) may help you to produce one such example.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I have added some data. This is what the dataframe looks like before groupby.

Comment: where is desiredx come from ?

Comment: sorry, desiredx is year. I was making the code generic when I posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values to plot on the y axis are `1` and `2`. You set the `ylim` to something bigger than `5`, `ylim=[5,20]`. Hence you do not see the values at `1` and `2`.

Setting the `ylim` to some reasonable numbers, e.g. `ylim=[0,3]` will allow you to see the data.

Also, `group.val1.plot` will plot the data against its index, because there is no `"year"` in `group.val1`. Instead take `"val1"` as the `y` value.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([['item1',2000,1, 2], ['item1',2001,1, 2], ['item1',2002,1, 2], 
              ['item2',2000,1, 2], ['item2',2001,1, 2], ['item2',2002,1, 2]],
              columns=['mykey', 'year','val1','val2'])

grouped = df.groupby('mykey')
for name,group in grouped:
  fig = plt.figure()
  ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
  group.plot.line(ax=ax1, ylim=[0,3], color='red',x="year",y="val1")
  ax1.set_ylabel('val1')
  ax2 = ax1.twinx()
  group.plot.line(ax=ax2, ylim=[0,3], color='blue',x="year",y="val2")
  ax2.set_ylabel('val2')
  plt.title(str(name), fontsize=15)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, The x is still not working. I get 0, 0.25,0.50 ..... on the x axis. The plots are y axis plots are now working.

Comment: The year is there now, but with a trailing .00 , .25 , .50 ....... And each year is repeated 3 times. so: 2000.00 , 2000.25 , 2000.50, 2001.00 and so on

Comment: Yes, that is to be expected. You will find a lot of questions and answers on formatting x axis labels around.

Comment: Wow this is so close. I have been working on this for days. Can you suggest a solution for the year format issue? I am searching for options too.

Comment: Google for "matplotlib format xaxis whole numbers" or "matplotlib format dates as years" or similar.

Comment: Fixed it by adding : xticks = [2000,2001,2002]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I have got the result what I wanted. Here is full tweaked version of the code, for anyone who may need it in future. I have added legend = False,  without this val1 and val2 are written on top of each other and looks messy.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 df = pd.DataFrame([['item1',2000,1, 2], ['item1',2001,1, 2], ['item1',2002,1, 2], 
          ['item2',2000,1, 2], ['item2',2001,3, 2], ['item2',2002,1, 2]],
          columns=['mykey', 'year','val1','val2'])

 grouped = df.groupby('mykey')
 for name,group in grouped:
  fig = plt.figure()
   ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
  group.plot.line(ax=ax1, ylim=[0,3], color='red',x="year",y="val1", legend 
  = False, xticks = [2000,2001,2002])
  ax1.set_ylabel('val1  ssssssss')
  ax2 = ax1.twinx()
  group.plot.line(ax=ax2, ylim=[0,3], color='blue',x="year",y="val2", legend 
  = False, xticks = [2000,2001,2002])
  ax2.set_ylabel('val2 dddddd')
  plt.title(str(name), fontsize=15)

   plt.show()
```